# Create a line as a secondary axis with Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, date, plotly, linechart

I have the following dataframe:

```
         date type   value
1  2020-01-01    N    7956
2  2020-01-01    R   55709
3  2020-02-01    N    2513
4  2020-02-01    R   62325
5  2020-03-01    N    1419
6  2020-03-01    R   63745
7  2020-04-01    N     350
8  2020-04-01    R   65164
9  2020-05-01    N   11500
10 2020-05-01    R   65050
11 2020-06-01    N    7208
12 2020-06-01    R   74550
13 2020-07-01    N    2904
14 2020-07-01    R   81158
15 2020-08-01    N   11054
16 2020-08-01    R   80841
17 2020-09-01    N    7020
18 2020-09-01    R   91445
19 2020-10-01    N   25448
20 2020-10-01    R   97776
21 2020-11-01    N    8497
22 2020-11-01    R  122479
23 2020-12-01    N   11154
24 2020-12-01    R  129813
```

I'm building the visualization below with this dataframe. My code so far is:

```
fig = px.bar(df_vintage, x='date', y='value', color='type',  
             labels={'type': 'value'}, category_orders={"type": ["R", "N"]})

fig.update_layout(
    title_text='Vintage Analysis',
    template='seaborn',
    margin=dict(l=50, r=50, t=50, b=50),
    legend=dict(yanchor="top", y=0.98, xanchor="left", x=0.02),
    
)

fig.update_xaxes(
    dtick="M1",
    tickformat="%b\n%Y")

fig.show()
```

[image]

I'm trying to insert a line visualization, with the percentage change of the total value, from month-to-month (but without the using the make_subplots from Plotly). To create the vector from the percentage change:

```
pct_change = df_vintage.groupby('dates').sum().pct_change().reset_index()
```

I'm referring to the blue line I draw in the visualization. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to avoid using `make_subplots` then you can draw the line using the [shapes](https://plotly.com/python/shapes/#vertical-and-horizontal-lines-positioned-relative-to-the-axis-data) module and iterating through your `pct_change` DataFrame to draw lines between the `i` and `i+1` element.

Unfortunately there isn't a second y-axis so the best I could was set the reference of the y-axis to "paper" which will draw the line as if the y-axis goes from 0 to 1 (e.g. a value of 0.5 in `pct_change` will appear halfway up the y-axis).

Since most of your percent changes are low, I added a constant value `base_pct_value` (which I set to 0.5) to the percent changes so they display above the bars while still showing the general trend in percent changes (I am assuming the trend of the line matters more to you than exactly where they are positioned on the y-axis)

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import io

df_vintage = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        """date type   value
1  2020-01-01    N    7956
2  2020-01-01    R   55709
3  2020-02-01    N    2513
4  2020-02-01    R   62325
5  2020-03-01    N    1419
6  2020-03-01    R   63745
7  2020-04-01    N     350
8  2020-04-01    R   65164
9  2020-05-01    N   11500
10 2020-05-01    R   65050
11 2020-06-01    N    7208
12 2020-06-01    R   74550
13 2020-07-01    N    2904
14 2020-07-01    R   81158
15 2020-08-01    N   11054
16 2020-08-01    R   80841
17 2020-09-01    N    7020
18 2020-09-01    R   91445
19 2020-10-01    N   25448
20 2020-10-01    R   97776
21 2020-11-01    N    8497
22 2020-11-01    R  122479
23 2020-12-01    N   11154
24 2020-12-01    R  129813"""
    ),
    sep="\s+",
)

fig = px.bar(df_vintage, x='date', y='value', color='type',  
             labels={'type': 'value'}, category_orders={"type": ["R", "N"]})

fig.update_layout(
    title_text='Vintage Analysis',
    template='seaborn',
    margin=dict(l=50, r=50, t=50, b=50),
    legend=dict(yanchor="top", y=0.98, xanchor="left", x=0.02),
    
)

fig.update_xaxes(
    dtick="M1",
    tickformat="%b\n%Y")

pct_change = df_vintage.groupby('date').sum().pct_change().reset_index()

## however far up on the y-axis you want the pct_change values to be drawn from, some value between 0 and 1
base_pct_value = 0.5

for i in range(1,len(pct_change)-1):
    fig.add_shape(type="line",
        x0=pct_change.iloc[i]['date'], 
        y0=pct_change.iloc[i]['value'] + base_pct_value, 
        x1=pct_change.iloc[i+1]['date'], 
        y1=pct_change.iloc[i+1]['value'] + base_pct_value,
        yref="paper",
        line=dict(
            color="skyblue",
            width=10,
        )
    )
    fig.add_annotation(
        x=pct_change.iloc[i]['date'], 
        y=pct_change.iloc[i]['value'] + base_pct_value,
        text=f"{pct_change.iloc[i]['value']:.2f}",
        showarrow=False,
        yref="paper",
        yshift=10
    )
    ## last iteration of loop
    if i+1 == len(pct_change)-1:
        fig.add_annotation(
        x=pct_change.iloc[i+1]['date'], 
        y=pct_change.iloc[i+1]['value'] + base_pct_value,
        text=f"{pct_change.iloc[i+1]['value']:.2f}",
        showarrow=False,
        yref="paper",
        yshift=10
    )

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Derek O. It solves the problem.

Comment: Do you have an idea of how could I insert the labels into this line?

Comment: Do you want to insert the percent increase at each point on the trendline?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Spent the whole morning into this.. haha

Comment: @bellotto you can reuse the for loop but use the `add_annotation` method for figs– I've updated my answer

Comment: My hero! Thank you a lot, man!!